# Return user's input data type

Tags: swift

In Swift is there any way to print out the data type of a user's input?

For example, if the user's input is

123
123.45
abc
123abc

Then the output should be

Integer
Double/Float
Var str
Var str

Comment: easy. all inputs are strings.

Comment: But if we treat numeric as string how to do calculation? just asking.

Comment: Then you need to convert the string to a numeric value using .toInt(). Otherwise use regexes or parse the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use regular expressions:

```
func getDataType(string : NSString) -> String {
    var integerRegex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[0-9]+$", options: nil, error: nil)
    var decimalRegex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^\\d*\\.?\\d*$", options: nil, error: nil)
    var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length)
    if (integerRegex.firstMatchInString(string, options: nil, range: range)) {
        return "Integer"
    } else if (decimalRegex.firstMatchInString(string, options: nil, range: range)) {
        return "Double/Float"
    } else {
        return "String"
    }
}
```

You may also retrieve number from the string:

```
func getNumber(string: NSString) -> AnyObject? {
    var type = getDataType(string)
    if (type == "Integer") {
        return string.integerValue
    } else if (type == "Double/Float") {
        return string.doubleValue
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```